# Where did my Wine file go?

Tags: 19.10

I followed the steps on the Wine website to use it with Ubuntu. It walked me through even the winecfg but there is no file when I try to find it.

I tried to install through the Ubuntu software but that also did not work. It will not launch.

My husband needs to be able to run Zbrush for work.

We are using Ubuntu 19.10. We are very new to this. We are not sure what to do. Any suggestions would be great and very appreciated.

Comment: Be sure to read https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1152

Comment: I followed the link you provided but I am not sure what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would check that access to the Windows program really works by manually running the wine command in a terminal window (CTRL-Alt-T) with the path and filename as one parameter.

On my system my Windows file system is accessible from ubuntu as "Local Disk", but it is also reachable as the parameter in my example:

wine "/media/roger/Local Disk/Program Files/HxD/HxD.exe"

The double quotes on the parameter are necessary because there's an embedded space in the path string.

Watch for case sensitivy as well.

BTW not so many Windows programs work with wine, but Organic Marble's link to winehq shows that Zbrush is good.`

Comment: How do I know what the file name is? I tried to find it a few times just by searching myfiles. I am not able to find anything that would even remotely look like a c drive. I think I might be confused.

Comment: I am taking an educated guess, but it will probably be a file calles ZBrush.exe. It will surely be located in a subfolder under "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)" depending on your particular computer. For Windows 7, click on Start, then type ZBrush.exe in that search box. For Windows 10, not sure where the search box is.

Comment: Sorry. I think I explained this wrong. I can find the zbrush files in windows 7. I am trying to find the c drive file on Ubuntu. I don't think I installed Wine properly.

Comment: OK got it. From ubuntu, I access my Windows 7 partition through its file manager's entry called "Other locations" then "Local Disk". On my wife's computer, her Windows 7 local disk is called "242 GB Partition" for a reason that escapes me. It lands you in the root of your Windows file system. If these entries are not available to your ubuntu account, then you would have to execute some permission changes to your media directories using Terminal (CTRL-Alt-T) and your sudo privileges. If all this already works, then I would imagine that wine uses what's there.